# React Native - Set a simple variable for useSelector

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I need to set a variable to use with useSelector (redux), and looks pretty simple but I don't know how to do it.

```
  const CATEGORY = cat;
  console.log(CATEGORY); // correctly get the strings 'food' or 'design'

  const getItems = useSelector(state => state.appDb.CATEGORY);
  console.log(getItems); // I get undefined
```

basically I would like to use the variable to set this:

`state.appDb.food` or `state.appDb.design`

What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: Are you sure that state.appDb.CATEGORY have value?
Try add console.log(state) just before  console.log(getItems)

Comment: yes. `console.log(CATEGORY); // correctly get the strings 'food' or 'design'`

Comment: Are you sure that state.appDb.CATEGORY === CATEGORY?

Comment: I don't understand this I just know that CATEGORY gives me back a  string 'food' or 'design'

Comment: Yes that's ok, but problem that you descibed that you have getItems undefined so basically this could be if state.appDb.CATEGORY  is undefined, that why asked to console.log(state) (NOT just CATEGORY)

Comment: Oh I think I've got what you try to get, can you try this:
`const getItems = useSelector((state, CATEGORY) => state.appDb[CATEGORY]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to use to `brackets notation` to access dynamic object keys like

```
  const CATEGORY = cat;
  console.log(CATEGORY); // correctly get the strings 'food' or 'design'

  const getItems = useSelector(state => state.appDb[CATEGORY]);
  console.log(getItems);
```